# Connection failure while connecting mssql server using datagrip ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, datagrip

I have remote mssql server database but when I try it connect to the database using datgrip on ubuntu . I am getting the following error:

> The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.xxx.xx.xx, port 1443 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall .

Comment: SQL Server default port is 1433 not 1443. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: So, did you check that SQL Server is running on port 1433? Did you check that remote connections are enabled? Did you check that any firewalls are not blocking traffic on that port? Basically, did you follow any of the instructions given to you in the error message?

Comment: It works now . The thing is someone gave me the wrong credential and I have also mistype the port also . Thanks everyone